# Fluent NHibernate não carrega tabelas filhas

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Tenho 3 tabelas relacionadas:
Lesson (Id (PK), Name)
LessonQuestion (Id (PK), LessonId(FK), Title)
LessonQuestionAnswer (Id (PK), LessonQuestionId(FK), Value)

Minha Model:

```
public class Lesson : Entity
{
  public virtual String Name { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<LessonQuestion> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class LessonQuestion : Entity
{
    public virtual String Title { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<LessonQuestionAnswer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class LessonQuestionAnswer: Entity
{
    public virtual String Value { get; set; }
}
```

Meu Mapeamento:

```
        public LessonMap()
        {
            Id(s => s.Id);
            Map(s => s.Name).Not.Nullable();
            HasMany(s => s.Questions)
                .Cascade.All()
                .Table("LessonQuestion")
                .KeyColumn("LessonId")
                .Component(s => { s.Map(x => x.Title); });
        }

    public LessonQuestionMap()
    {
        Id(s => s.Id);
        Map(s => s.Title).Length(1000).Not.Nullable();

        HasMany(s => s.Answers)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Table("LessonQuestionAnswer")
            .KeyColumn("LessonQuestionId")
            .Component(s => { s.Map(x => x.Value); s.Map(x => x.IsRight); });
    }

    public LessonQuestionAnswerMap()
    {
        Id(s => s.Id);
        Map(s => s.Value).Length(1000).Not.Nullable();
    }
```

Quando rodo o List obtenho o seguinte:

```
{
    "data": {
        "count": 1,
        "offset": null,
        "limit": null,
        "entries": [
            {
                "name": "Aula1",
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "title": "Title Question 1",
                        "answers": null,
                        "identifier": null
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Title Question 2",
                        "answers": null,
                        "identifier": null
                    }
                ],
                "identifier": "6670147eddd74d5cb51af9032afa9339"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Eu tenho registro na tabela LessonQuestionAnswer relacionado ao registro do "Title Question 1", mas não é carregado.

Alguem sabe dizer o que pode estar acontecendo?